# Uncaught ReferenceError in bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am working on a project on `MVC` in which I have added date time picker in the form field for that I have downloaded `bootstrap-datetimepicker`.

I have extracted `JS` and `CSS` Files to my project but still, it shows some error.

The Error is:

```
VM199:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.1.4.js:328), <anonymous>:2:42)
    at fire (jquery-2.1.4.js:3099)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery-2.1.4.js:3145)
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (jquery-2.1.4.js:3378)
    at jQuery.fn.init (jquery-2.1.4.js:2821)
    at jQuery (jquery-2.1.4.js:76)
    at eval (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.1.4.js:328), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery-2.1.4.js:328)
    at jQuery.fn.init.domManip (jquery-2.1.4.js:5435)
```

Comment: seems you have not included `moment.js` in your page?

Comment: Your code uses [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/), but that's not included in the page.

Comment: use only cdn of moment.js see if it is working, make sure moment.js is loaded before you use it.

Comment: The relevant message is not `Uncaught ReferenceError` but `moment is not defined`. Check that the momentjs library is included.

Answer (score 0):

For the Bootstrap datetimepicker to function correctly, the following set of files needed to added in the  tag

```
> jQuery
> Moment.js
> Bootstrap.js (transition and collapse features are required if you're not using the full Bootstrap)
> Bootstrap Datepicker script
> Bootstrap CSS
> Bootstrap Datepicker CSS
```

Initialise the datetimepicker

```
  $("#fromDate").datetimepicker({
              sideBySide: true,
              debug:false,
              useCurrent: false,
              format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
              }) 

<div class="input-group date" id="fromDate">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fromDate"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
```

DateTimepicker has lot of customisable features.To know more about it , refer to the [DateTimePicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my error it was due to duplicate function that was defined somewhere else in the code.